# SunPKCS11 provider not found with keytool

Tags: java, keytool, java-9, pkcs#11, java-security

I am running the following command with java 9 :

> ```
> keytool -keystore NONE -storetype PKCS11 -providerClass
>      sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 -providerArg pkcs11conf -list
> ```

and get the flowing error :

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Provider
>   "sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11" not found

In Java 8 it works.

How does one use keytool with SunPKCS11 provider?

Comment: @nullpointer Yes but this doesn't help with the main question: how to make `keytool` working

Comment: Can you try `-addprovider SunPKCS11`?

Comment: @AlanBateman Is that the flag for `Security.addProvider`

Comment: This is the option to `keytool` to specify the provider by name. You can use it with `-providerArg` to specify the argument to the provider.

Comment: Seems like [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/keytool.htm#JSWOR-GUID-5990A2E4-78E3-47B7-AE75-6D1826259549) is not updated with `-addProvider SunPKCS11`. You can alternatively try adding `-providerName SunPKCS11` to the command line as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was with my pkcs11conf file. Java don't like the single backslash in my DLL path :

> "C:\Path\to\my\pkcs11lib\mypkcs11lib.dll" : Wrong
>
> "C:\\Path\\to\my\\pkcs11lib\\mypkcs11lib.dll" : OK

The different between Java 8 and Java 9 is the error message.

Java 9 :

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Provider "sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11" not found
```

Java 8 :

```
keytool error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

I realized that when I added **-v** to the command.

Java 9 :

```
java.lang.Exception: Provider "sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11" not found
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:798)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:397)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:390)
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.ConfigurationException: Absolute path required for library value: xxx.dll
        at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.Config.parseLibrary(Config.java:682)
        at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.Config.parse(Config.java:392)
        at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.Config.<init>(Config.java:210)
        at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11$1.run(SunPKCS11.java:113)
        at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11$1.run(SunPKCS11.java:110)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.configure(SunPKCS11.java:110)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.KeyStoreUtil.loadProviderByName(KeyStoreUtil.java:285)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.KeyStoreUtil.loadProviderByClass(KeyStoreUtil.java:309)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:788)
        ... 2 more
```

Java 8:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: Error parsing configuration
        at sun.security.pkcs11.Config.getConfig(Config.java:88)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:129)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:103)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.ConfigurationException: Absolute path required for library value: xxx.dll
        at sun.security.pkcs11.Config.parseLibrary(Config.java:690)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.Config.parse(Config.java:398)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.Config.<init>(Config.java:220)
```